# Is the fictional script in Comet Lucifer decipherable?

Tags: comet-lucifer

*Comet Lucifer* features a fictional script that is used whenever text is shown. For example:

[image: script on Sogo's eyepiece]
[image: script on newspaper]

Is the script decipherable? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed decipherable - the script appears to be a straightforward substitution cipher for English written in the Latin alphabet. But I would hesitate to even call it a "cipher". The script in *Comet Lucifer* is less like [the script in *Rokka no Yuusha*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23509/), where decipherment is a genuine challenge, and more like [what *Akagami no Shirayukihime* uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX5ZF.jpg). That is, it's basically English written in a very exotic font. (Well, *Akagami* sometimes uses romanized Japanese rather than English, but the idea is the same.)

Consider this image from episode 1:

[image]

The headline on the left reads "Garden Indigo". If you squint right, you can see how the script really is just a hyper-stylized variant of uppercase Latin glyphs. And, as corroboration, recall that one of the military folks said "Garden Indigo" later in the episode.

Likewise, consider this image from episode 1:

[image: wanted posters]

What do these look like? "Wanted" posters, of course. And if you look hard enough, you'll see that the top line of the poster on the right looks a lot like a stylized version of the word "WANTED". If you look at the second line beneath the girl's picture on the same poster, you can match up the glyphs from "WANTED" to see that this says "-EWA-D". Fill in the blanks - which are both the same - and we conclude that this says "REWARD".

We don't have enough text as of episode 1 to construct a full translation table, but the general principle here is straightforward.